# NSUserDefaults: How to set up NSDictionary with NSString keys, and BOOL values?

Tags: nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I want to add an NSDictionary item to my NSUserDefaults settings bundle, but I am not sure how to structure the item inside the Root.plist file. The dictionary needs to contain NSStrings for keys, and Boolean values.

At the moment the item inside the .plist looks something like the following pseudo code:

```
Item 0 -- Dictionary 
   Key -- String -- Values
   Values -- Dictionary 
       item 0 -- String  -- Speed //Key 
       item 1 -- Boolean -- NO    //Value
       etc....
```

Is this correct? 
So in order to the read the Boolean value in my program I want to execute the following code.

```
BOOL speedValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"Values"] objectForKey:@"Speed"];
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost.  A `BOOL` isn't an object, so you'll need to get that out via an `NSNumber` or something.

Comment: There is a Boolean option in the plist editor which I have managed to use for reading/writing to a single boolean value, but I want to do this for multiple booleans held within a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Save:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:TRUE forKey:@"isEnabled"]
```

**load**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isEnabled"]
```